# What's the most efficient way to append elements while also escaping text, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm optimizing a bottleneck that, not surprisingly, is the result of tens of thousands of appends in a loop.

I'm familiar with the pattern of accumulating new elements as strings, then joining and inserting them in a single append.  But what if those elements have text content that needs to be escaped, i.e. would normally be set using `.text()`?

I'm currently creating these as separate elements, appending them to a container outside the DOM, then inserting that container.  Is there a faster approach?

Comment: Why cannot you escape the text using javascript? Even if it's regexes it's  (or should be!) much faster than using DOM.

Comment: yeah ur right in saying that `append()` would be a performance bottleneck, just concatenate them together like `text + text` and then append the whole chunk, even better build the block server side and then append it. If you need to use text just stick it all in a wrapper div and go $("#wrapper").text(block) and then append the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the accumulation-as-string method.  If you need to simulate the `text()` method, use the shown `escapeText` method like this:

```
var escapeText = function(s)
{
   return s.split('&').join('&amp;').split('<').join('&lt;').split('>').join('&gt;').split('"').join('&quot;');
};

var someArray = ....
var toInsert = '';
for (var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++)
{
   toInsert += '<p>' + escapeText(someArray[i]) + '</p>';
}
$('#foo').append(toInsert);
```